# Why does apt-get dist-upgrade change /usr/bin/ruby to /etc/alternatives/ruby?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, apt

When I run an apt-get update, apt-get dist-upgrade, the location of /usr/bin/ruby changes from /usr/local/bin/ruby to /etc/alternatives/ruby. This ends up breaking several cron jobs until I remember to correct it back. Why is it doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't move the binary, symlink it

```
ln -s /etc/alternatives/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

but better yet use [update-alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892877/how-do-i-make-ruby-1-9-the-default-ruby-on-ubuntu)

```
update-alternatives --config ruby
```

Oh and the **why**, there are multiple branches of *ruby* (ruby1.8 vs ruby1.9) similar to python2 vs python3 which affect script compatibility.